# How does instagram create huge thumbnails on its user's feeds

Tags: facebook-opengraph, instagram

I would like to understand how does instagram show large image thumbnails, with each thumbnail having individual actions such as Like and comment. Is it possible to do via the Open Graph API or is this due to Instagram being a property of Facebook?

The custom action and objects API does not seem to allow such a layout. An example is shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is supported by the API via the user generated photos functionality:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/
has the docs, and you need special approval for your actions

You add the following parameters to your existing publish calls:

```
image[0][url]=<URL TO IMAGE>
image[0][user_generated]=true
image[1]... etc
```

{edit:} Actually, i'm not sure how to render that aggregated unit - my answer above is for the photos functionality itself

Comment: _“Actually, i'm not sure how to render that aggregated unit”_ – it think how the aggregation is displayed just depends on the “Layout” setting for the aggregation. I guess Instagram is just using the “Gallery” layout here.

Comment: I did look at user generated photos. however I am under the belief that those are allowed only if the user took that image "with an actual camera". In instagram's case however it seems a like was sufficient to trigger the functionality.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense, sorry - i'm not sure how those are created, unless there's already a corresponding object in Facebook's graph for the photos which were liked (including the large picture)

Comment: Thanks so much for helping, I guess it's a facebook invitation-only feature.